# How can I get the style of a font?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So I want to determine if an element's font is `sans-serif`, `serif`, or `monospace` using JavaScript. This is for use in a Google Chrome Extension so it only has to work in Google Chrome.

The extension will be used for substituting fonts for every element with the browser's default fonts. So for instance, if the default sans-serif font is Arial, and an element's font was detected as being sans-serif, the element's font would be changed to Arial.

Also, since default fonts can be specified for multiple languages, would there be a way to determine the language of an element as well?

EDIT:

So what if I approached this by checking for if `sans-serif`, `serif`, or `monospace` was specified as a fallback font?

It seems I would have to iterate over every element in the document to determine the font applied to it. What would be the most efficient way to do this? Or can I do this without iterating through every element?

So here is what I came up with:

```
/* main.js */

var elements=document.getElementsByTagName('*');

for(var i=0;i<elements.length;++i){
    var fontFamily=getComputedStyle(elements[i]).getPropertyValue('font-family');

    if(~fontFamily.indexOf('monospace')){
        fontFamily='monospace';
    }
    else if(~fontFamily.indexOf('sans-serif')){
        fontFamily='sans-serif';
    }
    else if(~fontFamily.indexOf('serif')){
        fontFamily='serif';
    }
    else{
        fontFamily='';
    }

    elements[i].style.fontFamily=fontFamily;
}
```

And in the manifest.json:

```
"content_scripts":[
    {
        "matches":[
            "<all_urls>"
        ],
        "js":[
            "main.js"
        ],
        "run_at":"document_end"
    }
]
```

So if I'm correct, this would set the font of all elements to be a generic font, which is then substituted automatically by the browser?

Comment: I am not aware if fonts themselves contain any classification as sans-serif, serif or monospace; but I think that might rather be a classification that is applied from the “outside”, like the browser having a list that classifies the fonts it “knows” as such. Therefor (if I am correct in that assumption), you would need a list of all possible fonts to be able to look up into what category they fall.

Comment: And “determining the language of an element”, which means rather the language of it’s content, is a broad topic. There are the `lang` and `xml:lang` attributes, but those do not have to be set on the element itself, but can be set on ancestors instead. And in absence of those, the language of the document might also be specified via a `meta` element or an HTTP header.

Comment: A font list would be rather time consuming to create and would also limit the extension to just those fonts. So what if I instead check for if `sans-serif`, `serif`, or `monospace` was specified as a fallback font?

Comment: Well then you would be relying on the page author to have specified that correctly. If you can live with a “wrong” result if f.e. someone specified a serif font by name, and then used the generic family `sans-serif` after that (either deliberately or by accident), or not specifying a generic font family at all … yes, then you could do that.

Comment: Yes that would be one downside to doing it this way. Since there is a default font in Chrome settings, I figure if a generic font is not specified, it would use that font. Otherwise if a generic font is specified, I suppose I can deal with it potentially being incorrect.

Comment: If you don’t want to iterate over every single element, then you might want to iterate over the stylesheets and their rules instead – and then manipulate those rules that specify a `font-family`. Of course that would not catch any formatting applied via `style` attribute or per JavaScript … if you want to catch those as well, then iterating over every single element might be your only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the font type for the elements, you can try this approach: http://jsfiddle.net/vCmtk/1/

To get the language, there are a couple of workarounds.  You can get the current language/region by relying on the `navigator.language` function. If you are implementing i18n for your extension, then this function will retrieve the current language: `chrome.i18n.getUILanguage()`

Comment: _“You can get the current language/region by relying on the navigator.language function”_ – that is the browser’s UI language, but has nothing to do with the language of an HTML element’s content (and I think that is what OP is asking for.)

Comment: Yes I'm asking for the HTML element content language, although UI language could be used as a fallback perhaps.